# How to create DataRelation between two tables in many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have searched many hours on the internet about this problem I'm having, managed to find something close to what I was searching, but can't figure a part.

I have 2 tables in many-to-many relationship.
-Event(id, col1, col2)
-Participant(id, col1, col2)

And the connection between them is in table:
-Signup(id, idEvent, idParticipant)

Now, I want to have two DataGridView. On program run, one datagridview will be full with data from the Event table. And when I click a row from that datagridview, I want to show in the second datagridview all the participants, from the Participant table, that are signed up for the Event.

This is what I managed to do so far:

```
ds.Tables.Add(ctrl.EventToDataTable());
        ds.Tables.Add(ctrl.SignUpToDataTable());
        ds.Tables.Add(ctrl.ParticipantToDataTable());


        DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("EventSignup",
                                            ds.Tables["Event"].Columns["Id"],
                                            ds.Tables["Signup"].Columns["idEvent"],true);


        ds.Relations.Add(dr);

        dr =              new DataRelation("SignupParticipant",
                                            ds.Tables["Participant"].Columns["Id"],
                                            ds.Tables["Signup"].Columns["idParticipant"], true);


        ds.Relations.Add(dr);


        bindingSourceEvent.DataSource = ds;
        bindingSourceEvent.DataMember = "Event";

        bindingSourceParticipant.DataSource = bindingSourceEvent;
        bindingSourceParticipant.DataMember = "EventSignup.SignupParticipant";   // Here it's the problem

        gridEvent.DataSource = bindingSourceEvent;     

        gridParticipant.DataSource = bindingSourceParticipant;
```

I think the two DataRelation that I've created are good, but I don't know how to refer in the bindingSourceParticipant.DataMember to them.

If in the bindingSourceParticipant.DataMember I set it at EventSignup, it shows all the rows from the Signup tables when I select something from the first datagridview.

How can I show in the second datagridview rows from the Event table, that correspond to the rows selected in the first datagridview?

Thank you!